# How to use function helpers of Handlebar.js to display local variables?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, helper

I use handlebars helpers to display the menu in cases:

- No user log in
- User log in

This is my function helpers:
[image]

(user.user_fullname in line 35 is local variables)
And this is result:

[image]

In case I display directly at handlebars view, it gives the result I expected but with the functions helper it doesn't. How can I correct it?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to create this helper. With this approach, you would need to compile the return strings in your helper so that they can be interpolated as Handlebars templates. It seems to me that a better approach would be to use a [block helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html) and thereby include the HTML _within_ your template.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can correct it by this way

```
`${user.user_fullname}`
```